# Generalization and reuse of a part of template in scala (in playframework)?

Tags: scala, playframework

Well, I am trying to generalize few code in my scala template of playframework. For example I have a template scala code, in many other scala templates. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somethig">
@form(routes.Application.post()) {
                @inputText(Form("title"),args ='cols -> 80)
                <input type="submit">
            }
 <script>...................</script>
```

I want to make a function that will hold the previous code and when I would call it, It will write that for me. In one word I want to reuse it in other templates. So how to do that?

I have tried to define function in my scala template but since it has javascript as well, it starts debugging js as scala! So I can't use it, now what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

That function is called a `tag` in Play and is nothing else than mini-view, which you can call /include with params from other 'normal' views: check the [`Tags (they are just functions, right?)`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplateUseCases)  section in the doc.

For JS... afaik, there's still no good way for escape the JS in the Play views, so most secure way is avoiding placing JS directly in it. Instead import them as a common JS file in the document's head with `<script src="...`